# Create multiple array from single array in spring boot java

Tags: java, arrays, list, spring-boot, flatmap

Given that I have the array of :

```
Array1 = [100,10,Banana], [101,10,Apple], [102,14,Banana], [103,12,Mango] -- size :4
```

I want to create a new array which is grouped by the 3rd parameter of Fruits object.
So that my array becomes

```
ArrayFinal = [[100,10,Banana],[102,14,Banana]], [101,10,Apple], [103,12,Mango] -- size : 3
```

Need the help in respective to java 8.
I  heard that we can use the Map ,but can anyone give the small code sample or any other implementation guide.

Comment: you could iterate original Array1, then get the value of 3rd position and use a map<String, []> to add all arrays with 3rd position equal. Then iterate that map keys and create the new ArrayFinal

Answer (score 0):

Respective to java 8

You need to use [Collectors.groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) static factory method

Here is blog post explaining use of [java groupingby collector](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)